# Azure Cloud Service NotReady and self-reporting Unhealthy

Tags: deployment, visual-studio-2017, azure-cloud-services

I have an azure cloud service (classic) running a worker role. I am trying to deploy it from visual studio but something is wrong and I have no clue how to find out what is wrong. I've attached a remote debugger to the VM and here is the output:

```
[INFO]  Role 996fcd4bf41d4b86bd4e4fb1c52904b5.MyRole is reporting state NotReady with sub-status Unhealthy and details Role has reported itself as unhealthy..
[HEART] WindowsAzureGuestAgent Heartbeat.
[INFO]  Role current state: Unhealthy.
[INFO]  Recieved goal state information.
[INFO]  Execution status: StartSucceeded.
[INFO]  Role 996fcd4bf41d4b86bd4e4fb1c52904b5.MyRole is reporting state NotReady with sub-status Unhealthy and details Role has reported itself as unhealthy..
[INFO]  Role 996fcd4bf41d4b86bd4e4fb1c52904b5.MyRole1 has current state Unhealthy, desired state Started, and goal state execution status StartSucceeded.
[INFO]  Role 996fcd4bf41d4b86bd4e4fb1c52904b5.MyRole has current state Unhealthy, desired state Started, and goal state execution status StartSucceeded.
[HEART] WindowsAzureGuestAgent Heartbeat.
[INFO]  Role current state: Unhealthy.
[INFO]  Recieved goal state information.
[INFO]  Execution status: StartSucceeded.
[INFO]  Role 996fcd4bf41d4b86bd4e4fb1c52904b5.MyRole1 is reporting state NotReady with sub-status Unhealthy and details Role has reported itself as unhealthy..
```

The worker role is a .NET Framework 4.7.2 console app. osFamily for the service is 6. I don't get any configuration errors.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't enough info in your logs to determine the root cause so you will need to do some further investigation.  You can start with https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kwill/2013/08/09/windows-azure-paas-compute-diagnostics-data/, specifically Scenario #1.

Start with the Windows Azure Event Logs and see if anything obvious stands out, then check WaHostBootstrapper logs for the process that is not reporting healthy.  Also check Windows Application Event logs for any application failures.  The blog series goes into more details on this and some additional places to check.